# Dividing a single matrix by 2?

Tags: matrices

I have a $2 \times 2$ matrix 
$$ A= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
4 & 10  \\
16 & 24 \end{array} \right). $$
If I was to divide this matrix by  $2$, do I just perform division on each number giving
$$
\frac{A}{2}= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
2 & 5  \\
8 & 12 \end{array} \right),
$$ or is this wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. Your procedure is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, matrices do not work like "regular" numbers. What you mean to write is $$\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)A = \begin{bmatrix} 
2 & 5 \\
8 & 12 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Although it may seem like the same thing, as $A/2$, the notation means something. Matrices, typically, have different properties in terms of inverses than the $1 \times 1$ matrices--we can think of any scaler as a $1\times1$ matrix. If you would like to read more about this, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics).

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm aware they don't work like regular numbers through multiplication and such. However I was given a matrix called B and had to figure out B/2. Link was helpful also.

Comment: I wouldn't be so strict about *notation*, I've seen OP's way of writing it countless times.

Comment: @BlakeBit I am glad the link helped. I wouldn't worry about it too much if you are outside the mathematics departments! But all-in-all, yes; you just divide each entry by one half.